Is $(1-x+\epsilon x)$ asymptotic to $(1-x)$ for $x \in [0,1)$?
Let
$$
f(x,\epsilon) = \frac{1-x}{1-x + \epsilon x}.
$$
Is $f(x,\epsilon)=1$ for $x \in [0,1)$ when $\epsilon\to 0$?
If so, how to prove for the case when $x\to1$ and $\epsilon\to 0$?
Question 1:
Given a $x\in [0,1)$, when we take $\epsilon\to 0$, we have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0} f(x,\epsilon) = \frac{1-x}{1-x}=1.
$$
So, in this situation, $\lim_{x\to 1}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}f(x)=1$.
However, if we first take $x\to 1$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} f(x,\epsilon) = \frac{0}{\epsilon} = 0,
$$
and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \lim_{x\to 1} f(x,\epsilon)=0$.
It looks like we can have different asymptotic behavior of $f(x,\epsilon)$ for $x\to1$. What is the problem?
Question 2:
If I want to evaluate
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lim_{a\to 1}\int^{a}_{0}f(x,\epsilon)dx,
$$
can I move $\lim_{\epsilon\to 1}$ to after the integral sign so that
$$
\lim_{a\to 1}\int^{a}_{0}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(x,\epsilon)dx=
\lim_{a\to 1}\int^{a}_{0}1\cdot dx = 1?
$$
Question 3:
If the answer to Question 3 is yes.
Let $g(x,\epsilon)$ be a continuous and bounded function. Do we have the identity
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lim_{a\to 1}\int^{a}_{0}f(x,\epsilon)\cdot g(x,\epsilon)dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lim_{a\to 1}\int^{a}_{0} g(x,\epsilon)dx?
$$

(I was puzzled by this question for a while and tried to split it into a sequence of small correlated questions. This is NOT the homework/exam exercise I encountered.)

As an FYI, MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") will often be downvoted & closed. If you want meaningful help, please [edit] your post to include relevant context (see here for more), such as your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If need be, this is helpful for formatting math/LaTeX, & Approach0 is nice for searching up past questions.

@PrincessEeV Thanks for the tips. I added more details to my post.

"What is the problem?" There is no problem. You just found out that $f(x,\epsilon)$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$.
